# Node JS unit test case with jest and mocking mongoDB find operation

Tags: node.js, testing, jestjs, testcase

```
> main landing file

    //app.js
    const route = require("./routes/app-route");
    app.use('/api', route);
```

```
> routes are defined in this file

    //app-route.js
    router.get('/users', [authJwt.verifyToken], usersController.users);
```

```
> trying to write unit test case for this file with code coverage 100% so here i need to mock the User.find({}) to be empty once and return list of data another time.

    //user-controller.js
    exports.users = (req, res) => {
        User.find({})
            .then(users => {
                if (users.length === 0) {
                    return res.status(404).send({ message: "Users Not found." });
                }
                res.status(200).send({
                    message: "Users Found",
                    status: "success",
                    users
                });
            })
            .catch(err => {
                res.status(500).send({ message: err.message });
            });
    };
```

I wanted to write test case for node js controller.
wrote this piece of code but didn't worked but

```
test("find users with empty array", async () => {
        // arrange and act
        const mReq = {};
        const mRes = {};
        User.find = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
            return Promise.resolve([]);
        });
        let result = await UsersContoller.users(mReq, mRes);
        expect(result)
    });
```

I want to add expect conditions like status 200, 404, etc expect(result.status).toBe(404)